# Half white screen when rotate to landscape ionic 4 IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, screen-orientation

I am building an IONIC 4 app in portrait mode. I have forced the app to stay in portrait mode in config.ts file and everything works fine in both android and IOS

On some pages, I am using camera-preview plugin to customize the camera screen. It needed to be in landscape mode so used Screen Orientation plugin to force it landscape on that page and start the camera.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
        this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
        this.cameraPreview.onBackButton().then(()=>{
          console.log('Back button pushed');
          this.close();
        })
        // this.presentAlertConfirm()
        //make short delay of 500ms to start the camera preview
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.initCameraPreview()
        },500)
      }
    })
  }
```

Works fine in android.

But in IOS, half of the screen is covered in white as in the image below.

[image]

Please help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: Its strange behaivior , maybe in ios it is making this cause of not getting its time to calculate the viewport, maybe in ios try to put the preview code inside a setTimeout , try it if it is timing problem..

Comment: hello @MostafaHarb, I have tried it inside timeout giving 3 seconds time too. still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by modifying the size of the camera preview as

```
async initCameraPreview(){
    await this.cameraPreview.startCamera(
      {
         x: 0,
         y: 0,
         width: this.isIOS ? window.screen.height : window.screen.width,
         height: this.isIOS ? window.screen.width : window.screen.height,
         toBack: true, 
         previewDrag: false, 
         tapPhoto: false,
         camera: "back"
     }
   ).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }
```